# 404: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, maven, web, spring-framework-beans

when I  run the project on tomcat server and open browser **http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCDemo1/**  the page given below appears main-page.jsp is in webapp/WEB-INF/view/ folder). Tomcat works fine.
If main-page.jsp is in /webapp/folder, the page works fine.

What can be the reason of this and how can this be solved?

What I have done so far is
clean Tomcat work directory->clean->clean project->update maven dependencies

PAGE:

```
**HTTP Status 404 – Not Found**


Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.


Apache Tomcat/10.0.10
```

**HomeController.java**

```
  @Controller
    public class HomeController {
        
        @RequestMapping("/")                  
        public String showHomePage() {
            return "main-page";
        }
    }
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.denisa.springmvcdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**main-page.jsp**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome...</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>com.derya.springmvc</groupId>
            <artifactId>SpringMVCDemo1</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.3</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <release>11</release>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </project>
```